# How to enable Gzip on http-kit for minified ClojureScript?

Tags: heroku, clojure, gzip, http-kit

My Clojure application is deployed on Heroku along with a minified 600KB+ ClojureScript JS artifact that I'm serving as a static file at `/js/main.js`.

How do I enable gzip compression on http-kit to reduce the size of my JS artifact over the wire?

Answer (score 0):

Not supported by http-kit, usually you want to use a proxy like Nginx anyways. As you probably don't have that option with Heroku you can do the compression via ring middleware, see this [issue](https://github.com/http-kit/http-kit/issues/19) for pointers.